# An error with annovar

Tags: vcf, sequence-annotation, maf, wes

I want to install annovar but in one particular part I always get this error

```
i1d18@RBGO-Server2:/data2/RNASeq/Angel/annovar$ perl annotate_variation.pl -downdb -webfrom annovar avsnp147 humandb/
NOTICE: The --buildver is set as 'hg18' by default
NOTICE: Web-based checking to see whether ANNOVAR new version is available ... Done
NOTICE: Downloading annotation database http://www.openbioinformatics.org/annovar/download/hg18_avsnp147.txt.gz ... Failed
NOTICE: Downloading annotation database http://www.openbioinformatics.org/annovar/download/hg18_avsnp147.txt.idx.gz ... Failed
WARNING: Some files cannot be downloaded, including http://www.openbioinformatics.org/annovar/download/hg18_avsnp147.txt.gz, http://www.openbioinformatics.org/annovar/download/hg18_avsnp147.txt.idx.gz
fi1d18@RBGO-Server2:/data2/RNASeq/Angel/annovar$
```

Googling did not return any clue

Any help please?

Comment: My first attempt would be to change the version of the genome build to something more recent than hg18.

Comment: I don't think hg18 is the issue, according to their documentation hg18 is supported. However, the commands you used are not exactly the same as they showed in [the tutorial](https://annovar.openbioinformatics.org/en/latest/user-guide/startup/). Did you try to do exactly what did suggested? If that still does not work, I would suggest to open [an issue](https://github.com/WGLab/doc-ANNOVAR/issues/new) on their github.

Comment: Changing to hg38 solved the problem, thanks